# Using WP Cli ib localhost

Tags: wordpress, import, wp-cli

I use Openserver + WP + WP Cli (local).
And I want import all images (which I have uploaded in /wp-content/uploads) via WP Cli `wp media import` command.
How I must add the path to the media files if they in:
c:\OpenServer\domains\golf.loc\wp-content\uploads\
I use: wp media import ~/wp-content/uploads/**/*.jpg
and receive an Error: reason file doesn't exist. No images imported.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in the import,

check this ,

```
wp media import ~/wp-content/uploads/**\/*.jpg
```